# ORMLite - QueryBuilder with Date condition

Tags: sqlite, date, time, ormlite

My sqlite database column is defined like this:

```
  @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
  public Date dateFound;
```

when I open sqlite broswer I see it is defined like this:

```
  'dateFound' TIMESTAMP
```

Now I create QueryBuilder:

```
DateTime time=new DateTime();
DateTime minusDays = time.minusDays(4);
QueryBuilder<Record, Long> queryBuilder = DatabaseHelper.get().getRecordDao().queryBuilder();
Where<Record, Long> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.ne("amount",0);
where.or();
where.ge("dateFound",minusDays.toDate());
System.out.println(queryBuilder.prepareStatementString());
```

And output is:

```
SELECT * FROM `record` WHERE (`amount` <> 0 OR `dateFound` >= ? )
```

which is not correct, I even tried with `new Timestamp(minusDays.toDate().getTime())` and resulting query was same..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by casting date which probably is not best way but its working:

```
DateTime time=new DateTime();
DateTime minusDays = time.minusDays(4);
QueryBuilder<Record, Long> queryBuilder = DatabaseHelper.get().getRecordDao().queryBuilder();
Where<Record, Long> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.ne("amount",0);
where.or();
where.raw("cast(`dateFound` as INTEGER)>= "+minusDays.toDate().getTime());
```